# Google Place Picker Search Bar text Color not Change iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api

### This is my Code Please review 4th line where i set color but it will show me Error

```
 let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UISearchBar.appearance.textField.setTextColor = UIColor.red
    UISearchBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    self.present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: this line `UISearchBar.appearance.textField.setTextColor = UIColor.red` shows error

Comment: yes, This line show me Error

Comment: Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]
  } else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is worked for latest swift version

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white] as [String:Any]
```